# React Navigation - Auth Flow - Error The specified child already has a parent on Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm trying to implement an Auth Flow on react native with react-navigation as it's done in the doc (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow). But when the state change in order to show the HomeNavigator I get the following error (only on Android, it's work on iOS) :

```
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
...
onCreateView (ScreenStackFragment.kt:129)
...
```

```
// App.tsx
return (
    <ReduxProvider store={rootStore}>
          <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
            <RootNavigator />
          </NavigationContainer>
    </ReduxProvider>
  );

// RootNavigator.tsx
export const RootNavigator = selectConnect(selectCurrentUser)((props: Partial<CurrentUserProps>) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        gestureEnabled: true,
      }}>
      {props.isAuthenticated ? (
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeNavigator" component={HomeNavigator} />
      ) : (
        <Stack.Screen name="LoginNavigator" component={LoginNavigator} />
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
});
// Note : selectConnect is just a custom function to use connect (redux) with selector
```

I can found any solution for this problem, so any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

**Environment**
React-Native: 0.66.0
@react-navigation/native: 6.0.4
@react-navigation/native-stack: 6.2.2
Running OS : Android (work fine on iOS)

Edit: Breaking news, it's seem to be due to @react-navigation/drawer (that need react-native-reanimated) but both are for now unused in my project (it still an issue because I will need these soon).
@react-navigation/drawer: 6.1.6
react-native-reanimated: 2.3.0-beta.2 (the only version that support react native 0.66.0)

Minimal project to reproduce : https://github.com/LaGregance/ErrorAuthFlowReactNavigation

Comment: Are you using react-native-maps?

Comment: No I don't use react-native-maps (a search of "react-native-maps" in node_modules, also return 0 result)

Comment: @MichaelBahl is there an issue when using reanimated with react-native-maps, because im trying to do a simple animation of a View inside a MapView and is giving me OP's error ?

Answer (score 1):

For those who facing the same issue I have temporary fixed it by downgrading react-native to version 0.65.1 and react-native-reanimated to 2.2.2
So obviously it an issue of react-native-reanimated.

I will now refer to : https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/2501

Comment: Discovering this issue now after upgrading to 0.66.1, thanks for posting this comment and opening an issue!